# org.hibernate.MappingException :No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

Tags: jdbc

When I am trying to fetch the record from a table in SQLServer2008 am getting the exception called: org.hibernate.MappingException :No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9 why?

Although the config file is correct.

Comment: Am using Hibernate4.0 to fetch from Sqlserver2008

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/565413/ORM/java/No-Dialect-mapping-JDBC-type#2567622

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed the query and explicitly cast it to varchar and it worked.......

```
String myquery = "select cast(t2.name as varchar) column_name from sys.objects t1 inner join sys.columns t2 on t2.object_id = t1.object_id"+
" left join sys.indexes t3 on t3.object_id = t1.object_id and t3.is_unique = 1 left join sys.index_columns t4 on t4.object_id = t1.object_id and t4.index_id = t3.index_id and t4.column_id = t2.column_id where (upper(t1.type) = 'U' or upper(t1.type) = 'V') and upper(schema_name(t1.schema_id)) = 'dbo' and upper(t1.name) = 'TEST'";
```

Answer (score 10):

It's the problem of hibernate mapping types.

you can extends a dialect.
eg:

```
public class SQLServerDialectOverrider extends SQLServerDialect{
    public SQLServerDialectOverrider() {
        super();
        registerHibernateType(Types.NVARCHAR, Hibernate.STRING.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, Hibernate.TEXT.getName());
    }
}
```

Use this class as the dialect class.

Comment: Where does this class should be implemented? In which package?

Comment: You can implement it anywhere you want. Just configure it as the dialect class in hibernate XML file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs if you are accessing the database table data in the different format on which its store in database
Example:
in data base column type is "nvarchar" and you are accessing data as a string via hibernate.
To avoid this you can add scalar in hibernate which will explicitly cast the column data as per requirement. scalar can be added in java while executing the query also in the hbm.xml file.