# I get the exception org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate. I wrote a native sql query.
This query  will be executed in sqlSever command prompt.

```
try
    {
        session=HibernateUtil.getInstance().getSession();
        transaction=session.beginTransaction();

        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT AP.PROJECT_NAME, AP.SKILLSET, PA.START_DATE, PA.END_DATE, RS.EMPLOYEE_ID, RS.EMPLOYEE_NAME, RS.REPORTING_PM FROM RESOURCE_MASTER RS,SHARED_PROPOSAL S, ACTUAL_PROPOSAL AP, PROJECT_APPROVED PA, PROJECT_ALLOCATION PL WHERE RS.EMPLOYEE_ID = PL.EMPLOYEE_ID AND PA.PROJECT_ID = PL.PROJECT_ID AND PA.SHARED_PROPOSAL_ID = S.SHARED_PROPOSAL_ID AND S.ACTUAL_PROPOSAL_ID=AP.ACTUAL_PROPOSAL_ID");
            List<Object[]> obj=query.list();
            Object[] object=new Object[arrayList.size()];
             for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                 object[i]=arrayList.get(i);
                System.out.println(object[i]);
            }
            arrayList.get(0);
            String name=(String)arrayList.get(0);
            logger.info("In find All searchDeveloper");

    }catch(Exception exception)
    {
        throw new PPAMException("Contact admin","Problem retrieving resource master list",exception);
    }
```

I am getting the following exception: **org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9**

This query is executed in SqlServer command prompt. I mapped seven tables.
If I remove the ACTUAL_PROPOSAL AP table, it executes correctly.

please help me

Comment: Likely related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991866/org-hibernate-mappingexception-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes when **the hibernate dialect is unable to find the corresponding java data type for the db column type**. To solve it you need to specify the data type of each result item with `addScalar()` method.

for example,

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID,NAME,BIRTHDATE FROM CATS")
 .addScalar("ID", Hibernate.LONG) 
  //If u r using newer version of hibernate use new LongType()
  //instead of Hibernate.LONG
 .addScalar("NAME", Hibernate.STRING)
 .addScalar("BIRTHDATE", Hibernate.DATE)
```

Read the API docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13646) or an example [here](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql.shtml).

Comment: A think that you do not need to define the data type for *all* columns, just for the ones that are special.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update. ManuPK is correct but Hibernate.String, Hibernate.Date, Hibernate.Long are deprecated. See http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5138