# JPA native query returns no records

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, nativequery

This is method to get Module entites within specified level for related backend.

```
public List<Module> getModulesWithinLevel(Long backendId, ModuleLevel... levels) {
        String joinedLevels = serializeLevels(levels);
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT M.* FROM MODULES M JOIN ROUTING_SEQUENCES RS ON RS.BCK_ID = M.MOD_ID WHERE M.MOD_LEVEL IN (?) AND RS.BCK_ID = ?", Module.class);
        query.setParameter(1, joinedLevels);
        query.setParameter(2, backendId);
        List l = query.getResultList();
        return l;
    }
```

When i execute the exact query in sql developer i get one row as result.
But this method returns empty List. No errors in logs - just empty list.
What is wrong with my native query?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the 2 parameters you're setting there are not the same ones you put in the query you run in sql developer. Another possibility is that because of the data types, hibernate or oracle are casting something, and that causes the query to return no values. Can you post the parameters you seen in Java and the query you're executing in SQL developer? also adding the mapping might help to find the issue.

Comment: I am setting right values - i am sure. But you second statement is probably true. When i remove Module.class param from native query i get "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9". Afteer quick search i came to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991866/org-hibernate-mappingexception-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9)
I implemented it, no exception is thrown, but still no results returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found answer to the original question but i did a little workaround by implementing entity for the ROUTING_SEQUENCES table with composite key.
This works well:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Module m WHERE m.id IN (SELECT rs.id.moduleId FROM RoutingSequence rs WHERE rs.id.backendId = :backendId) AND m.level IN (:levels)", Module.class);
query.setParameter("backendId", backendId);
query.setParameter("levels", Arrays.asList(levels));
return query.getResultList();
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROUTING_SEQUENCES")
public class RoutingSequence extends AbstractEntity<RoutingSequencePK> implements Auditable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RoutingSequencePK id;

    @Column(name = "RS_MANDATORY", nullable = false)
    private Boolean mandatory;

    @Column(name = "RS_ORDER")
    private int order;

    @Column(name = "RS_INSDTTM")
    private Date insertDate;

    @Column(name = "RS_UPDDTTM")
    private Date updateDate;
...
}
```

Id

```
@Embeddable
public class RoutingSequencePK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "BCK_ID")
    private Long backendId;

    @Column(name = "MOD_ID")
    private Long moduleId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you leave the ? in there by mistake?

Try...

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT M.* FROM MODULES M JOIN ROUTING_SEQUENCES RS ON RS.BCK_ID = M.MOD_ID WHERE M.MOD_LEVEL IN (:1) AND RS.BCK_ID = :2", Module.class);
```

Comment: I dont know this :1 syntax. I think using ? is correct. [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Native_SQL_Queries).

Comment: Ahh!!! I remember this! hibernate behaves slightly different when you use the `in` operator with a positional or named parameter. I remember that in a project, about 4 years ago, we had to use the named parameters for queries that used `in`, as it didn't work properly with positional parameters. @Dominik, use your preferred search engine and search for **hibernate named parameters** to see how to use them.

Comment: Ah ok, I have never seen the ? reference before...yes in Hibernate you use :paramName in the query string and query.setParameter("paramName", joineLevels); etc.

Comment: I rewrited query to use named params, but same result. 
I tried the hibernate session.createSQLQuery(..) with named params as well, but same result again.