# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

Tags: oracle, hibernate, tomcat, weblogic

I'm having a trouble with a native SQL query...

When this code :

```
SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
List<Object[]> objects = entityManager.createNativeQuery(" select ERROR_CODE, REASON,
count(*) " + //
" from flow_error " + //
"where timestamp " + //
" between to_date(:endDate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') " + //
" and to_date(:startDate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') " + //
" AND TRANSACTION_UUID in ( " + //
" SELECT TRANSACTION_UUID " + //
" FROM RJT_HIST " + //
" WHERE insert_tst " + //
" between to_date(:endDate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') " + //
" and to_date(:startDate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') " + //
" and flow_number = :flowNumber) " + //
" GROUP BY ERROR_CODE, REASON")//
.setParameter("endDate", sdfDatetime.format(endDate))//
.setParameter("startDate", sdfDatetime.format(startDate))//
.setParameter("flowNumber", flowNumber)//
.getResultList();
```

is used on a tomcat server v5.5, the code works well and dont return any exception. 
But the problem appears on a weblogic server (v10.3.6).
I'm getting an Mapping exception from hibernate :

```
2014-06-17 17:57:02,727 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default 

(self-tuning)'] ERROR com.btoc.reporting.web.misc.MiscServletFilter - Error processing request
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:526)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:253)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:65)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at com.btoc.reporting.web.misc.MiscServletFilter.doFilterInternal(MiscServletFilter.java:25)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:637)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:74)
    at com.btoc.reporting.web.monit.service.RejectionServiceImpl.retrieveErrorFromIntervalAndFlow(RejectionServiceImpl.java:178)
    at com.btoc.reporting.web.monit.RecordedDashboardController.getErrors(RecordedDashboardController.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1796)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:65)
    ... 79 more
```

I cant figure out why.
Any guess ?
Thanks by advance.

Comment: Have you looked at other questions with the exact same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991866/org-hibernate-mappingexception-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9

Comment: Hi, I've alreaduy checked that question but i'm not using a SQLserver but an Oracle server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally the solution was indeed like [org.hibernate.MappingException :No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991866/org-hibernate-mappingexception-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9)

I was looking at the wrong dialect.. This was for SQLServer and i'm using Oracle10gDialect.
So i've made this class :

```
public class Oracle10gDialectOverrider extends Oracle10gDialect{

public Oracle10gDialectOverrider(){
    super();
    registerHibernateType(Types.NVARCHAR, Hibernate.STRING.getName());
}

}
```

And specify into my hibernate xml : Oracle10gDialectOverrider instead of Oracle10gDialect

Thanks

Comment: Since Hibernate 4 `StandardBasicTypes.STRING` should be used instead of `Hibernate.STRING`

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because I accidentally set classpath with ojdbc16.jar instead of ojdbc14.jar.  A lot of answers out there to cast the data, which works, or to upgrade the dialect, which probably also works. Just wanted to list this in case anyone else had application dependent on the older jar.