# Query in SQL Server giving error while running the same query with MySql working fine

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate

I have the following query,  and executing through hibernate.

```
String userIdQueryString = "select distinct user_id from l_catalog_user_object_access  where REPORT_HEADER_ID in ("
                        + " select REPORT_HEADER_ID from l_report_header_data "
                        + " where report_types_id in (select REPORT_TYPES_ID from l_report_types where display_value like '%Report') )"
                        + " and user_id = :userId";
```

When I have connected to SQL Server, getting below error,

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
```

When I have connected to MySql, it working fine without any error.

```
Here I am using the dialect for SQL Server,
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

For MySql I am using,
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Any help/suggestions.

Comment: `and user_id = :userId` is not correct syntax, you need `and user_id = @userId`

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991866/org-hibernate-mappingexception-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9

Comment: you probably set wrong hibernate settings, you have to use correct dialects for different dbs

Comment: @siggemannen 
Here I am using the dialect for SQL Server,
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

For MySql I am using,
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Comment: @purush, add this info to the question instead!

Comment: i have a feeling you're doing something wrong, because if ppl had problems using hibernate with NVARCHARs, i'm pretty sure it would be fixed quite quickly. Perhaps your settings aren't correct.

Answer (score 1):

Look, you have not given anywhere near enough information to help:

- Where is the code which calls this query?
- Where are the mapped entities?

*However*, note that `-9` is the JDBC type code for the SQL type `NVARCHAR`, as defined by `java.sql.Types`.

Now, SQL Server handles "nationalized" (i.e. Unicode) strings *very differently* to MySQL. So it's completely unsurprising when things related to `NVARCHAR` columns behave a bit differently between the two databases.

Things which affect this in Hibernate include:

1. the `@Nationalized` annotation, and
2. the setting `hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data`.

Beyond that there's not much I can tell you because you have not told us very much.